# Como llenar directamente una Gridview desde Textbox en asp.net con C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, gridview

Estoy buscando otra manera de llenar mi Gridview desde cajas de texto y la única manera que encontré fue ocupar Viewstate para agregar los encabezados de mi tabla y poder lograr que se agregaran fila por fila sin que se borrara cada vez que daba click en agregar.

**Así que quisiera saber si hay otra forma de llenar la Grid, Muchas gracias por la ayuda**

**aqui cargo los encabezados de la gridview**

```
 public void cargar()
    {       DataColumn Codigo = dt.Columns.Add("Codigo", typeof(Int32));
            DataColumn Articulo = dt.Columns.Add("Articulo", typeof(string));
            DataColumn Marca = dt.Columns.Add("Marca", typeof(string));
            DataColumn Estilo = dt.Columns.Add("Estilo", typeof(string));
            DataColumn Proveedor = dt.Columns.Add("Proveedor", typeof(string));
            DataColumn Categoria = dt.Columns.Add("Categoria", typeof(string));
            DataColumn UnidadM = dt.Columns.Add("UnidadM", typeof(string));
            DataColumn Bodega = dt.Columns.Add("Bodega", typeof(string));
            DataColumn Costo = dt.Columns.Add("Costo", typeof(string));
            DataColumn Cantidad = dt.Columns.Add("Cantidad", typeof(string));
            DataColumn PrecioVenta = dt.Columns.Add("PrecioVenta", typeof(string));
            DataColumn Total = dt.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(string));
            ViewState["Records"] = dt;
        }




    }
```

**aqui lleno la Gridview desde los textbox y los drowdanlist al darle click al boton**

```
 protected void Agregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        dt = (DataTable)ViewState["Records"];

        row["codigo"] = this.GridCompra.Rows.Count + 1;
        foreach dt 
        row["Articulo"] = DropDownArticulos.SelectedItem;
        row["Marca"] = DropDownMarca.SelectedValue;
        row["Estilo"] = DropDownDiseño.SelectedValue;
        row["Proveedor"] = DropDownProveedor.SelectedItem;
        row["Categoria"] = DropDownCategoria.SelectedValue;
        row["UnidadM"] = DropDownUMedida.SelectedValue;
        row["Bodega"] = DropDownBodega.SelectedValue;
        row["Costo"] = txtCosto.Text;
        row["Cantidad"] = txtCantidad.Text;

        row["PrecioVenta"] = txtPrecioVenta.Text;
        var Total = (Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidad.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(txtCosto.Text));
        row["Total"] = Total.ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        GridCompra.DataSource = dt;
        GridCompra.DataBind();



        
    }
```

Comment: otra forma.. que no implique ir y volver? o que seria otra forma? que no implique que cosa?

Comment: otra forma de agregar datos a la grid, que no sea usando ViewState o una variable de session